# Set containment of MinimumBadPrefix and BadPrefix of a Safety Property

Tags: automata, formal-methods, model-checking

This question is related to formal model checking theory, but I cannot find a tag for it.

Let $P_{safe}$ be a safety property.

$BadPref(P_{safe})$ is the set of bad prefixes for $P_{safe}$

A Safety property $P_{safe}$ over Atomic Proposition $AP$ is regular
if its set of bad prefixes is a regular language over $2^{AP}$

Is the following true?

1. If $L$ is a regular language with $MinBadPref(P_{safe}) \subset L \subset BadPref(P_{safe})$,
   then $P_{safe}$ is regular.
2. If $P_{safe}$ is regular, then any L for which
   $MinBadPref(P_{safe}) \subset L \subset BadPref(P_{safe})$ is regular.

My attempt to 2. is that it's true

$P_{safe}$ is regular then $MinBadPref(P_{safe})$ is regular and so is $BadPref(P_{safe})$. A NFA $N$ recognizing $BadPref(P_{safe})$ can be obtained by adding self loops on the final states of the NFA $M$ recognizing $MinBadPref(P_{safe})$. And $L$ is recognized by some NFA containing a subset of the self loops added to $M$. Therefore $L$ is regular.

And what about 1.?

Comment: Can you explain what *BadPref* and *MinBadPref* are? Also, to anticipate my next question, explain what kind of object *Psafe* is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sure, I completed my question with the missing info.

Comment: Note that this is exercise 4.4 from Baier&Katoen, Principles of Model Checking. As for your attempt to 2., you don't have $MinBadPref\subset BadPref$, since $bb$ is not contained.

Comment: @KlausDraeger does $MinBadPref(P_{safe})=\{ab, aabb\}$ work?

Comment: From the definition, $MinBadPref$ contains all those $w\in BadPref$ which do not have a proper prefix $u\in BadPref$ (so in particular, you cannot choose it - it is determined by $BadPref$). In this case ($BadPref=\{a^pb^q|p,q>0\}$) you get $MinBadPref=\{a^pb|p>0\}$, and then your $L$ won't work.

Comment: @KlausDraeger thanks, so I took another attempt to 2. but still can't find a clue for 1.

Comment: If $BadPref(P_{safe}) - MinBadPref(P_{safe})$ is infinite, then you can encode an arbitrary (read: uncomputable) set in $L$.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't really get the above, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @xiamx What I mean is that, given regular sets $A\subset C$, it is the case that all sets $B$ satisfying $A\subset B\subset C$ are regular if and only if $C-A$ is finite. The idea is that, if $C-A$ is infinite, then (e.g.) you can use the presence/absence in $B$ of the $k$th least string in lexicographic order of $C-A$ to encode the $k$th bit of [Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat e.g. A=a* b and C=a* b* then A-C = a* b b*, so not all sets B are regular?

Comment: @xiamx Assuming that you meant $C-A=a^*(\epsilon\cup bbb^*)$, then yes.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat taking $B = a^* b^p$ where p is prime, then $A\subset B \subset C$ is satisfied but B is not regular. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

For (1), I will only give a sketch at first, in case you want to work it out yourself; I can add some details later if you want. Try proving the following:

$w\in BadPref$ if and only if $w$ has a prefix $u$ which is in $L$.

(2) is already covered quite well by David's comments.